# Angular is give me an "ERROR null" message in VSCode, how can I determine what is causing it?

Tags: angular

[image]

When I compile my Angular v17 project, I am seeing the above ERROR messages in the terminal, as shown. The problem is, I don't know what's causing them? There is no link or line # reference. The console in the web browser is not showing any errors at all. How can I go about determining the source of the errors?

Comment: just to make sure, when you say compile your project, does it mean running `ng serve`?

Comment: Andres2142 - Correct. This is a fairly new, small project. It has some small reactive forms that create, edit, delete/list of a single simple object. It stores the data using localstorage. When I run "ng s" it compiles with no errors. As soon as the first page reloads in the browser, the errors above show up in the IDE console. There are no errors in the browser console. The errors shown above have no info, no context. Could be code, a plugin, who knows? I'm not sure where to even start?

Comment: What external packages are you using? Try deleting the `package-lock.json` along with `node_modules` and run again `ng serve`

Comment: Additionally, make sure the `npm` version and `nodejs`  version you are using is compatible with `Angular v17`

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, the error was somehow caused when saving data to local storage. I'm honestly not sure why the error existed. The code causing it was a standard

```
localStorage.setItem('myData', 'myValue');
```

type of call.

At the end of the day, the code in question was honestly just a "stub" to test my pages with until I got the data service in place. Once that happened, I no longer needed the buggy code, so I got rid of it.